# MS BotBuilder : How can I set a combination of an intent and an entity to trigger a dialog?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using the MS BotBuilder to create a bot language understanding bot. I have a dialog `readProfile` that's triggered on `Read` intent that is trained on LUIS.

```
 bot.dialog('readProfile', [
        function (session, args) {
            var entities = args.intent.entities;
            console.log("entities : ", entities)

    ]).triggerAction({
        matches: 'Read'
    }).cancelAction('cancelReadProfile', "Ok.", {
        matches: /^(cancel|nevermind)/i
    });
```

The LUIS model is trained to recognise entities like `Profile` and others so I do get the entity in console.

However, I wish to trigger the dialog only if the entity recognised is `Profile`. I can set some logic to work only when the entity in args is `Profile` but wondering if there's a builtin / more elegant way to do this.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a logic statement in the first step of the readProfile dialog is the best way to do this. If no Profile entity is found, end the dialog with a message like "It looks like you're trying to read a profile, but didn't I couldn't figure out what profile you're trying to read." This has the advantage of giving the user some feedback about their action and helping them figure out what they need to fix.

You could try to train the Luis model to have a strong correlation between having a Profile entity and the Read intent. Enter a few utterances that are really close to the Read intent but don't include a Profile and mark them with the None intent. That doesn't guarantee that it won't ever match a Read intent without a Profile, though, so I'd still recommend the above step.

Comment: Actually, if I allow myself a logic statement, I can simply use a switch case over the profile, that's what im doing right now, but want to not do it.